# How to create a button that will execute javascript function in Viaualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, button

I'm trying to create a button on a visualforce page that when clicked will execute a javascript get to submit a form to a remote page.  I would truly appreciate any help!  Thanks in advance!

```
 click: function(event) {
            if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                var my_phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
                var my_agent_id = localStorage.getItem("agent_id");

                $.get("https://mywebsite.com/scripts/connect.aspx", {
                    scriptName: "click_to_dial",
                    bus_no: "456",
                    scriptID: "12345",
                    skill_no: "280218",
                    p1: "voice_mail",
                    p2: my_phone,
                    p3: my_agent_id,
                    p4: "not_now",
                    p5: "my_wait_to_callback",
                    Guid: "1a1a1b1nbbf1a1233455666"
                });;
                var popupElement = Apperyio("voicemail_pop");
                if (popupElement.popup("option", "positionTo") === "origin") {
                    popupElement.popup("open", {
                        transition: "pop",
                        positionTo: "#" + $(this).attr("id")
                    });
                } else {
                    popupElement.popup("open", {
                        transition: "pop"
                    });
                };
```

Comment: This is a jQuery function. Have you already included jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

On Visualforce:

```
<apex:commandbutton onclick="doSomething(this.event); return false;">
```

In the script:=

```
function doSomething(event) {
    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
        var my_phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
        var my_agent_id = localStorage.getItem("agent_id");

        $.get("https://mywebsite.com/scripts/connect.aspx", {
            scriptName: "click_to_dial",
            bus_no: "456",
            scriptID: "12345",
            skill_no: "280218",
            p1: "voice_mail",
            p2: my_phone,
            p3: my_agent_id,
            p4: "not_now",
            p5: "my_wait_to_callback",
            Guid: "1a1a1b1nbbf1a1233455666"
    });
    var popupElement = Apperyio("voicemail_pop");
    if (popupElement.popup("option", "positionTo") === "origin") {
        popupElement.popup("open", {
            transition: "pop",
            positionTo: "#" + $(this).attr("id")
        });
    } else {
        popupElement.popup("open", {
            transition: "pop"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwani!  Where would I define the script?

Comment: JamesD it would be on vf page wrapping in script tag.

Comment: ok - cool!  I didn't realize that this is a jquery funciton.  do i need to use a static resource to include the jquery library?

Comment: I added the jqeury includes and it looks like it's working! let me dig into this a little and I will update the thread with my code.  Thanks again for your help!